# Как получить список файлов из папки через WebApi?

Tags: c#, .net-core

Подскажите пожалуйста, как реализовать метод WebApi, который бы вернул мне список файлов из папки, но в JSON ответе путь к файлам был бы по типу
http://localhost:5000/file1.txt,http://localhost:5000/file2.txt.
Первое что пришло в голову это

```
[HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<string> Get()
    {
        return Directory.GetFiles(@"D:\DIR-300NRUrevBx").ToList();
        //Тут у меня в параметрах нужная мне папка.

    }
```

Но получаю в ответ такое.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Каким образом мне получить пути к файлам с учетом сайта?

Comment: Что значит `с учетом сайта`?

Comment: @tym32167 ну может я не так выразился, просто хочу в JSON получить ссылки на файлы из нужной мне папки.

Comment: @Petr Скажите пожалуйста, результат работы кода, приведенного выше, соответствует выводу на картинке? Потому что, мне кажется, что ответ на данный запрос будет выглядеть примерно так: ```System.Collection.Generic.List...```.

Comment: @LetsDrum это скриншот из браузера, где js делает запрос на метод и я получаю такой ответ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не могу понять только зачем такое нужно кому-то.

```
[HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<string> Get()
    {
        var hostAddress = $"{this.Request.Scheme}://{this.Request.Host}{this.Request.PathBase}";
        return GetFileList(hostAddress, @"D:\images");
    }

    private IEnumerable<string> GetFileList(string hostAddress, string path)
    {
        List<string> resut = new List<string>();
        foreach (var fi in Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
        {
            var fileName = Path.GetFileName(fi);
            resut.Add($"{hostAddress}/{fileName}");
        }

        return resut;
    }
```

Comment: Ну а как мне по WebApi отдать список файлов в папке по другому?
Задача в целом такова, что мне надо получить от сервера пути к файлам а на клиенте через JS я буду воспроизводить видео, JS будет формировать некое подобие плейлиста на основе таких вот ссылок.

Comment: 1) отдавать файлы клиенту должен же не API, а обычный Http web server из внутр. директорий в `wwwrooot`. А у него, по всей видимости, будет несколько другой ip адрес и порт, хотя конечно, можно зафигачить 2 в 1. 2) По идее сканировать диск на поиск и составление списка файлов не самая практичная задача. Пути к файлам должны быть уже заранее прописаны в БД и в случае запроса извлекаться оттуда, ну просто по здравому смыслу должно быть так. А представьте как вы нагрузите диски, если десяток человек будут качать видео в то время когда другие 20 будут запрашивать список этих файлов.

Comment: Видимо я просто не правильно изначально поставил для себя задачу. Как то из головы вылетело, что есть свой wwwroot и можно БД для хранения прикрутить. Спасибо вам:)

Answer (score 1):

**Варварское** решение

```
[HttpGet]
public string Get()
{
    var path = @"D:\DIR-300NRUrevBx";
    string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(path);

    var baseUrl = Request.Url.Scheme + "://" + Request.Url.Authority + Request.ApplicationPath.TrimEnd('/') + "/";

    return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(files.ToList()
        .Select(x => x.Replace(path + "\\", ""))
        .Select(x => baseUrl + x));
}
```

**Результат** (где path = @"D:\Downloads"):

```
[ 
   "http://localhost:63564/Adobe Illustrator.exe",
   "http://localhost:63564/code-carbon.png",
   "http://localhost:63564/Erik_Frimen_Elizabet_Frimen_-_Patterny_Proektirovania_Head_First_O_39_Reilly_-_2011.pdf",
   "http://localhost:63564/jenkins-2.204.1.zip",
   "http://localhost:63564/Martin_Fauler_-_Shablony_Korporativnykh_Prilozheniy.pdf"
]
```

Comment: Кстати в  `core 3` выпилили  нафиг Newtonsoft.Json и заместо него свой напилили, говорят быстрее работает.

Comment: @Bulson Да, видел. Находится в System.Text.Json, если не ошибаюсь.

Comment: Именно так.....